# Develop from Windows, run on a command-line Linux virtual machine

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, linux-distributions

I've always developed web apps on my Windows pc in a Linux virtual machine (programs and frameworks not always have full compatibility with Windows, but I find Windows handy for other reasons, so that's why I have this setup).

Virtual machine, though, sometimes makes the environment slow, so I'd like to have a different setup (a little bit odd).

I'd like to have **a command-line Linux virtual machine in which the app is run**, and I'd like to **develop the app using my Windows text editor**, saving my work in the virtual machine.

Is there a method to do this?

Comment: use `putty` to access `VM` from windows over ssh protocol and configure `sshd` and `samba` in a `VM`

Comment: Can you create a complete answer so I can mark it as an answer? (Do you recommend some linux distros or particular configurations?)

Comment: Why am I getting downvoted for this?

Comment: because there are a lot of snobs around here who has forgotten that she was a child some time ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from using `VM`'s console interface that is provided by the most (if not all) of Windows hosted `Virtual Managers`, you could use [putty](http://www.putty.org/) at your windows desktop to access a `VM` running `Linux` with `sshd` daemon to allow `putty` to connect and `samba` service configured to 'export' some location inside `VM`'s fs to allow you access the files over the network connection.

Perhaps, you would need to access this share by `IP` address from Windows workstation, not by its `netbios` name, i.e. `\\192.168.100.2\sharename` where the `192.168.100.2` is the `IP` of your `VM`.

As for `Linux` distro -  it's a matter of taste and any recommendation would make an answer an opinion based. So, pick the one most familiar to you.

Answer (score 1):

[cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/?l=en) + whatever text editor you want. You can use sublime text as a remote file manager - connected over sshfs or ftp. Set up your editor under preferences, rightclick on a file, pick edit.

Edit the file, and when you save it, it automatically uploads it to the linux system. I suspect this would also work with many IDE/text editors.